# Data is saved in Firebase in a different order than it is transferred SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a data saving to Firestore in the application. In code, it looks like this:

```
db.collection("flowers")
                        .document()
                        .setData(["Name":self.flowerName,
                                  "Cup width":self.cupWidth,
                                  "Cup height":self.cupHeight,
                                  "Stem length":self.stemLength,
                                  "Leaf width":self.leafWidth,
                                  "Leaf length":self.leafLength])
```

but in Firestore it looks like this:

```
Cup height: "1"
Cup width: "1"
Leaf length: "1"
Leaf width: "1"
Name: "Rose"
Stem length: "1"
```

I want them to be saved in the database in the same way as they are transferred in the application. I guess they're sorted alphabetically in the database, but can it be changed? I looked for any information in documentation, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: You use Dictionary, it is unordered container.

Comment: Why do you want them saved in the database in a particular order? When reading, you can access those fields in any order you like. The console displays all data lexicographically as @frankvanpuffelen mentions in his answer and also as you mentioned but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking.  If you can clarify what you're asking we may be able to provide a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore stores the data in JSON format, which is by definition unordered. So the order in which you pass the fields to the database, has no impact on the order in which they are stored.

The Firebase console displays the fields in alphabetical order, although I'm not sure if that is guaranteed.

Of course you can display them in the UI of your app in the required order.